# How to Install a module on Drupal 8 in a docker environment when D8 asks for FTP credentials. (Devilbox)

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-8

Technology used:
 - Windows 10
 - [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)
 - [DevilBox](http://devilbox.org/)
 - Drupal 8.6.4
(Optional tech: [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to simulate linux commands).

When attempting to add a new module via URL or file upload in Drupal 8, the site asks me for FTP credentials and I have no more ideas where to find or set them.

I have a basic install of Devilbox running a brand new installation of Drupal 8. (Devilbox is a dockerized php stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem I bypassed finding the FTP credentials.

I will change the accepted answer to the first correct answer that is not mine and a bypass.

First step, stopped using cygwin. Started using Powershell. 
Next step, navigate to the site's installation within devilbox:

```
/devilbox/data/wwww/<yoursite>/htdocs
```

Then run command:

```
composer self-update
```

Followed by:
`composer require drupal/<drupal module to add>`

Magically, module is under the modules page on drupal 8.